# Safely cast to unsigned char *

Tags: c++, casting

If I need to treat something as an `unsigned char` array, is this the correct way for a function:

```
int main() {
    int i = 500;
    f(&i);
}

void f(void *ptr) {
    unsigned char *byteptr = static_cast<unsigned char *>(ptr);
    ...
}
```

What if I don't have a function? Should I use two `static_cast`, first to `void *` and then to `unsigned char *`?

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cast a pointer to your `int` variable to an unrelated type like `unsigned char`, you will need to use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
unsigned char *byteptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&i);
```

But I echo the commenter's question: what are you actually trying to do? It seems unlikely that anything useful can come of casting `int *` to `unsigned char *` like this.

Comment: That shall be my new name. "The Commenter". :D

Comment: C++ objects are made up of bytes, which can be accessed via character types. You can copy those bytes around, and sometimes even copy them back to the original object. This is explicitly permitted by the standard.

Comment: @n.m.: Explicitly? Chapter and verse, please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: 3.9.2

Comment: If `int` pointers and `unsigned char` pointers are of different size, isn't `reinterpret_cast` unsafe?

Comment: @potrzebie No it isn’t. A `reinterpret_cast` between `(unsigned) char*` and the original object type is explicitly allowed by the standard. By contrast, I’m actually not sure if your original code is – as far as I remember you may only cast between `void*` and the original type, your code thus violates strict aliasing rules.